# Есть ли возможность использовать механизм запросов Linq без сохранения данных в БД?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, linq

Не совсем понимаю как правильно сформулировать мой вопрос, но... существует следующая проблема.
Есть DataGrid, который привязан к набору сущностей. Изменяя свойства в гриде, изменяются свойства у сущностей. Есть ли возможность использовать механизм запросов Linq без сохранения данных в БД? При использовании Linq в данном случае он опять делает запрос к БД, где старые данные. А если пройтись циклом, то он видит изменения

```
foreach (var item in context.Docs)
{
    if (item.flag == true)
        MessageBox.Show("True");
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. LINQ — механизм _выборки_ данных, он не может в принципе их менять.

LINQ читает информацию из своего источника. Если вы поменяли информацию в UI, убедитесь, что ваш LINQ-запрос видит изменённые Entity.

Comment: Как мне кажется, я и не писал, что Linq меняет данные. Данные меняются в UI, в DataGrid. Linq делает запрос к базе данных, а мне нужно узнать, могу ли я использовать Linq с несохраненными в БД данными

Comment: @IsM: ну, а запрос у вас к `DataGrid` или к источнику данных для `DataGrid`? Расскажите подробнее о том, что вы делаете. (Может быть, [это](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16490601/276994) ваш случай.)

Comment: Есть датагрид, ItemSource={Binding}
В это время я делаю 

    ObservableCollection<Doc> docs = new ObservableCollection(context.Docs);
    this.DataContext = docs;

Потом в UI происходят изменения(грубо говоря просто ставаятся галочки в гриде). И теперь вопрос: если я прохожу циклом, как показано в вопросе по context.Docs, то я могу видеть изменения. Можно ли также обратится к уже измененным данным с помощью linq...
При этом я не хочу делать context.SaveChanges()

Comment: @IsM: Ну, LINQ не делает ничего такого особенного, так что должно работать. А что такое `context` в вашем примере?

---
А, вижу. А если вы пробегаетесь по `(IEnumerable<Docs>)this.DataContext`, тоже не работает? (Может, `DataGrid` создаёт в `docs` новые Entity, которых нету пока в `context.Docs`?)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю Linq to Entities переводит все это дело в запрос к БД, а там все прежние несохраненные данные, соответственно изменения, сделанные в UI оно не увидит, в отличие от простого цикла.
И да, по IEnumerable проход linq тоже работает не так, как хотелось бы

Comment: @IsM: Вряд ли. `ObservableCollection` — не `IQueryable`, а `IEnumerable`, то есть данные отвязаны от базы данных. Другое дело, что элементами являются Entity. Думаю, ошибка не там, где вы ищете. Покажите код, что вы делаете, что ожидаете, и что получаете на самом деле. (И да, проход по `(IEnumerable<Docs>)this.DataContext` обязан работать.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context.Docs.Load()
```

загружаешь все записи из Бд, затем используешь Local

```
context.Docs.Local
```

загруженные локально записи к гриду биндишь через Local

```
context.Docs.Local.ToBindingList()
```

линк запросы тоже делаешь к Local

```
context.Docs.Local.Where(w=>w.flag==true).ToList()
```

Comment: Как оказалось, что EntityFramework сейчас использует DbContext вместо ObjectContext и там нет метода Load()

Comment: Все, прошу прощения, разобрался. Все работает без Load.